# Extract text from borderless table from an image in Python

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, data-extraction

I am new to opencv and need help in extracting text from a borderless table present in an image. Need to extract text from the below image. [image: Input Image]

I want to extract text and put the information in a data frame.

Expected output
[image: Expected Output]

Comment: Have you found a suitable solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Extracting borderless tables using openCV alone is a bit of a challenge. However, you can use [paddleocr](https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR) to detect and OCR the table.
Below is a code sample:

```
import cv2
import pandas as pd
from paddleocr import PPStructure

table_engine = PPStructure(recovery=True, return_ocr_result_in_table=True)


img_path = 'table_image.jpeg'
img = cv2.imread(img_path)
result = table_engine(img)

for line in result:
    line.pop('img')
    if line.get("type") == "table":
        html_table = line.get("res").get("html")
        html_data = pd.read_html(html_table)
        pd.DataFrame(html_data[0])
```